# Connect ROS with RobotStudio via abb_robot_driver

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I installed the abb_robot_driver node from [here](https://github.com/ros-industrial/abb_robot_driver) in my workspace, it worked without any errors while building.

I am running:

- Ubuntu 20.04, kernel: 5.14.0-1054-oem
- ROS Noetic

I have now installed Robot studio on a seperate Windows PC, Robot Ware 7 is also installed. I open the robot I want (ABB IRB4600-40/255) and create a controller. It is indicated that the controller is running.

When I now try to use the first example of the abb_robot_driver [here](https://github.com/ros-industrial/abb_robot_driver/tree/master/abb_robot_bringup_examples) which is:

```
roslaunch abb_robot_bringup_examples ex1_rws_only.launch robot_ip:=<WindowsPC IP>
```

I get the warning

```
[ WARN] [1667469851.804625427]: Failed to establish RWS connection to the robot controller (attempt 1/5), reason: 'Failed to collect general system info'
```

Until I receive:

```
[FATAL] [1667469856.931221918]: Runtime error: 'Failed to establish RWS connection to the robot controller'
```

I am pretty sure I did not set up everything correctly, but was not able either to find a tutorial how to do so. Can anybody give me a hint? Thank you.

Cheers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/408918/connect-ros-with-robotstudio-via-abb_robot_driver/) by [joff](https://answers.ros.org/users/99933/joff/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2022-11-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, here is my update: I shut off all firewalls of the Windows PC (I switched to a VM). I was able to ping from both directions this way. I still was not able to connect to the virtual controller of RobotStudio. For that I needed to follow this instuction [here](https://forums.robotstudio.com/discussion/12082/using-robotwebservices-to-access-a-remote-virtual-controller). Afterwards I was able to launch the first example of the bringup. I still have issues with the bringup examples but I'll open another question for that.
Thanks for the help!

---

Originally posted by [joff](https://answers.ros.org/users/99933/joff/) with karma: 40 on 2022-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I have now installed Robot studio on a seperate Windows PC, **Robot Ware 7 is also installed**

`abb_robot_driver` (or more specifically, `abb_librws`) is not compatible with RW7. This is mentioned in the readme of the `abb_egm_hardware_interface` package, [Requirements](https://github.com/ros-industrial/abb_robot_driver/tree/32eb0f48abfd3358cb5a4f3f043f1306a9811b24/abb_egm_hardware_interface#requirements) section:

> RobotWare version `6.07.01` or higher (less than `7.0`).

And in the `abb_librws` readme, [Important Notes](https://github.com/ros-industrial/abb_librws/tree/4864181c67c57f0e46809e6eacb667a161ee2d08#important-notes) section:

> RobotWare versions `7.0` and higher are currently incompatible with abb_librws

There is some work (in a fork of `abb_librws`) to add compatibility with RW7, but I'm not certain what the status of it is.

Refer to [ros-industrial/abb_librws#147](https://github.com/ros-industrial/abb_librws/issues/147).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-11-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joff](https://answers.ros.org/users/99933/joff/) on 2022-11-04**:
Thanks for the answer. I installed the most recent robot ware version below RW 7, which is, 6.14.00.1. I still cannot connect to the simulated robot. The error is still the same. I tried connecting both computers via ethernet and put them into the same subnet. I cannot ping the windows pc's ip address though, could that be the issue?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-11-04**:
I would suggest to check the firewall configuration of the Windows PC.

It's likely/possible you'd have to give RobotStudio permission to accept incoming traffic from hosts on your network.